# Bring back right Windows Key

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, wireless-keyboard

I just bought a new Microsoft Wireless 850 keyboard, and noticed that in the new model the right windows key, between the option key and the right Alt key, has been replaced with a Fn key. I'm used to running shortcuts using the right Win Key, and feel completely crippled not having it.

I went back to the shop to replace it with a different keyboard, but it turns out that **everything** they have on stock, from various manufacturers (Logitech, Apple, Dell, etc) is the same - no right Win Key, but a Fn key instead.

This is really annoying me to the point I want to physically break things. Is there some way to assign this silly Fn key to behave like a WinKey? I'm open to everything - hardware, software, drivers, everything. I'm desperate.

I use OSX El Capitan (10.11.6) and Windows 10, so would ideally be looking for a solution for both.

Comment: No; What you want is unrealistic; check online stores for a greater variety of keyboards

Comment: Easiest solution for Windows is to use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) and re-map an unwanted key to RWin. (e.g. `RCtrl::RWin`). I'm not sure what you can use for Mac though. I don't think you can remap `Fn` keys since the OS receives no input when you press them. [They only work in conjunction with other keys to modify their behavior so you can't remap them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key#Technical_details).

Comment: If you are open to pressing two keys together to emulate the right Windows key, you could do that as well with AutoHotkey. Something like `~AppsKey & RCtrl::Send {RWin}`. With that script running, pressing the AppsKey and RCtrl key together (press AppsKey first) will work as RWin key, otherwise they work like nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, 8, 7, or Vista, the simplest solution is to download and instal [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/). It allows you to remap any key to another function.

On Mac you have two options.

**MacOS/OS X System Preferences:**

For system wide keyboard shortcuts, try checking the **Keyboard** pane in **System Preferences**, then open the **Shortcuts** tab.

**Use the free app Karabiner:**

If you are using OS X El Capitan or lower, [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) can be used to fine tune the functionality of any key on your keyboard.

Sources:

- How-To Geek: [Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows 10, 8, 7, or Vista](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)
- MakeUseOf: [Remap Your Mac’s Function Keys To Do Anything You Want](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remap-macs-function-keys-anything-want/)

Comment: Thanks. I use OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 (edited my post to note that). I just tried to install Karabiner. Seems like it has what I want, but it just doesn't work. Where did you learn that it doesn't work? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Seems like Karabiner has a setting to map Fn+something to Command+something, which is exactly what I need. However, I tried it and it seems like it only impacts the Macbook's keyboard, it doesn't impact my external wireless USB keyboard.

Comment: Are you able to remap it through `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts`?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem like System Preferences lets you assign shortcuts with Fn key in them, not even the internal keyboard's Fn key.